# Access a progress that work background with nohup (LINUX) -get foreground

Tags: python, linux, server, nohup, foreground

I am working on a chat program with Python. I would like to use nohup because users always can access server when I am logout. 
I could run nohup very well. It was great.But I am a admin and I can write messages,and can see online users as using python. after I worked nohup, and logout, when I login I can't access the python progress. I want to foreground it again. 
Yeah, I can see it in background with `ps -aux` . I see its PID,STAT but I don't know how to access it. I should access it.`jobs` doesn't see it. `fg` don't work. or I can't do. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you `nohup` a process, when you log out the parent of the process switches to being `init` (1) and you can't get control of it again.

The best approach is to have the program open a `socket` and then use that for ipc. You probably want to split your code in to 2 pieces - a daemon that runs in the background and keeps a socket open, and a client which connects to the socket to control the daemon.

Comment: I am thinking of  write 2 pieces. First is for only keeps a socket open and run background, and second is that access socket and command the server. First piece will understand commands by looking IP. What do you think about it? Thanks for your interest

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html for some options.